# Stuck on Mock Inputs

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, roman-numerals

So, I'm trying to write a roman numerals converter. Never used unittest tests before, but here's what I have so far. I'm just trying to test the value of "DLXII" to be 562. It runs just find in the main program. But, every time I try to do a test with (python -m unittest test_roman_numerals), it just runs the program and I have to input "DLXII" for the test, unless that's how the test works. I was trying make the test function automatically do that for me. Thanks.

roman_numerals.py

```
class RomanNumeral: 
"""A class to represent our roman numerals or integers."""
def __init__(self, number): 
    """Initializes the user's input, a counter, and standard values for each roman numeral."""
    self.number = number
    self.int_num = 0 # counter
    self.rom_dict = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000} 

def roman_to_int(self): # Probably better to use a linked list here.
    """Takes in user_input in roman numerals and return the equivalent integer."""
    rom_values = list(self.rom_dict.items())
    for i in range(len(self.number) - 1): 
        for j in range(len(rom_values)): 
            if self.number[i] == rom_values[j][0]: 
                self.int_num += rom_values[j][1] 
                for k in range(j+1, len(rom_values)):
                    if self.number[i+1] == rom_values[k][0]:
                        self.int_num -= 2*rom_values[j][1] 
    for l in range(len(rom_values)):
        if self.number[-1] == rom_values[l][0]:
            self.int_num += rom_values[l][1]  
    return self.int_num 

def isroman(self):
    """Checks if user input is a roman numeral."""
    for i in self.number:
            if i not in self.rom_dict.keys():
                return False
    return True

def roman_or_int(self):
    """Checks if user input is a roman numeral, integer, or not."""
    if self.IXC_triple_rules() is True:
        return False
    elif self.isroman():
        print(self.roman_to_int())
    elif self.number.isdigit():
        print("number")
    else:
        print("Entry is neither roman numerals or integers.")

def IXC_triple_rules(self):
    """Tag if user input has more than 3 I, X, or C."""
    if "IIII" in self.number or "XXXX" in self.number or "CCCC" in self.number:
        print("You cannot have more than three I, X, or Cs in a row")
        return True

def non_subtractive_numberals(self):
    """Tag for V, L, and D. Can never be subtracted."""

user_input = input("Enter a number in roman numerals: ")
x = RomanNumeral(user_input)
x.roman_or_int()
```

test_roman_numerals.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from roman_numerals import RomanNumeral

class TestRomanNumerals(unittest.TestCase): #sublcass of test case class
    """A test class for our Roman numerals."""

    @patch('builtins.input', return_value="DLXII")
    def test_roman_to_int(self, mock_input):
        result = RomanNumeral("DLXII").roman_to_int()
        self.assertEqual(result, 562)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your top-level code under a `__main__` block, or it'll get executed every time you import the file (including in your test):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = input("Enter a number in roman numerals: ")
    x = RomanNumeral(user_input)
    x.roman_or_int()
```

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the while loop. Just didn't know how top-level code works with unittest. Thanks a lot.